# Ошибка PHP при установке laravel

Tags: linux, laravel

Ставлю Laravel на Linux Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS через composer.

Пишу в командной строке:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel --prefer-dist
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of 
packages.

Problem 1
 - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.7 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP 
extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.5.6 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP 
extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.5.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.5.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.5.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.5.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.5.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.5.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.4.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.4.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.4.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.4.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.4.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.3.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.3.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.2.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.2.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.2.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.2.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.2.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.1.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.1.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.1.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.1.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.1.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.0.9 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.0.8 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.0.7 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.0.6 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.0.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.0.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.0.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.0.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.0.13 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.0.12 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.0.11 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.0.10 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.0.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.0.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- Installation request for phpunit/phpunit ~6.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[6.0.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.10, 6.0.11, 6.0.12, 6.0.13, 6.0.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.8, 6.0.9, 6.1.0, 6.1.1, 6.1.2, 6.1.3, 6.1.4, 6.2.0, 6.2.1, 6.2.2, 6.2.3, 6.2.4, 6.3.0, 6.3.1, 6.4.0, 6.4.1, 6.4.2, 6.4.3, 6.4.4, 6.5.0, 6.5.1, 6.5.2, 6.5.3, 6.5.4, 6.5.5, 6.5.6, 6.5.7].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
 You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Можно как-то это все исправить одним махом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение:

Обновил версию PHP до 7.1 вот так https://www.jakelprice.com/article/how-to-upgrade-from-php-70-to-php-71

Потом сделал следующее:

```
composer update
composer require cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable
```

После этого все стало без проблем.

Answer (score 1):

Подключите расширение php-xml, в зависимости от системы установка отличается. На linux - через менеджер пакетов, для apt будет так `sudo apt-get install php-xml`. В windows просто раскоменьтьте соответствующую строку в файле php.ini, который находится в директории установки php

Comment: подключил, перегрузил apache2 на всякий случай, ставлю - получаю ту же длинючую ошибку...

Comment: @Oktu может отличаться текст, но суть одна - надо доустановить модули

Comment: вообще странно, я месяц назад делал установку без проблем, видимо с одним из обновлений пришли эти ошибки...

Comment: @Oktu возможно. Я ларавел 5.3 последний раз юзал, тоже такое было, решалось установкой модулей, указанных в ошибках

Comment: каждый поодиночке ставить?